# Tableau: Have fixed weekday names (Sunday to Saturday) as columns

Tags: tableau-api

Below is the sample data:

[image]

I am trying to build a single combo bar chart representing number of orders booked, shipped, and delivered on a given day of week (Sunday through Saturday). For ex: August 1 was a Monday: Booked-4, Shipped - 2, Delivered - 1 should be the three columns and so on.

I am using DATEDIFF and time based filters to count the distinct orders. The issue that I am having is that I cant use WEEKDAY function corresponding to any particular date i.e. Booked, Shipped, Delivered as it messes up the count. I want to use fixed values for weekdays as columns. Is it possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, you can [PIVOT](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/pivot.html) it in the data window so all the dates are in one column. With that done, it would be simple to create what you're describing.

[image: sample]

See attached sample workbook. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60455118/160810%20stack%20question.twbx

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I am dealing with MySQL server datasource. So, pivoting isn't an option

Comment: That can be done in SQL as well. Try to UNPIVOT your data. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx