# MySQL joining 3 tables on a column keeping all its distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join 3 tables:
Table A: Date, CountOfHonda(Integer)
Table B: Date, CountOfToyota(Integer)
Table C: Date, CountOfMazda(Integer)
I want the result table as: Date, CountOfHonda,CountOfToyota,CountOfMazda

All the dates might not be present in all 3 tables. I want to, in a sense, combine the tables without eliminating or duplicating any date value in the final table. If a Date is missing in a table, the value of the corresponding count column can be null/0. Thanks!

Comment: I think you have a bad designed database

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili that's true. no primary keys, no references and why put CountOfCars as a separate column, in a separate table!? i would have used one table probably. `cars` with columns, `car_brand` and date.

Comment: I have to do this as a work around for generating Tableau report and not sure how can I achieve this in tableau. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38863197/tableau-have-fixed-weekday-names-sunday-to-saturday-as-columns

Comment: I agree. It sounds like your schema is broken

Comment: Well.the DB looks more like in the link in my comment above. Would be great to know a better way to get from table I have in the link above to the result of this question.

Comment: Seriously. See normalisation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a tally (or lookup) table, for instance, DateLookupTable.

This table would have a single column, Date, with values from 01/01/1900 - 12/31/2099 (or whatever range is appropriate.

Then you do..

```
select d.Date, a.CountOfHonda, b.CountOfToyota, c.CountOfMazda
from DateLookupTable d
left join tableA a on a.Date = d.Date
left join tableB b on b.Date = d.Date
left join tableC c on c.Date = d.Date
where d.Date between (startDate) and (endDate)
```

Tally/lookup tables are invaluable in many situations.

Comment: My understanding is that a wanted date is always present in one of the three tables.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, this requires hard coding a date range. That could be fixed by finding the min and max dates in each of the tables, however, that would make for a more complicated query. However, as the replies to the original question state, the schema is probably far from perfect and any queries are going to be less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

use `full outer join simulation`.

basically you do this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.Date = tableB.Date
UNION
SELECT * FROM tableA
RIGHT JOIN tableB  ON tableA.Date = tableB.Date
UNION
SELECT * FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableC ON tableA.Date = tableC.Date
UNION
SELECT * FROM tableA
RIGHT JOIN tableC  ON tableA.Date = tableC.Date
```

don't worry about the dates which are not present in other tables. that's what the `"outer" join` is for. it would still keep those rows.

*Edit*: forgot mysql didn't have a full outer join. but this should take care of your query.

Comment: the reference page show how MySQL doesn't have an `outer` or `full` join implementation. but you could simplify `outer` join into `left/right` joins and use them. my example is based on it.

Comment: but..i understand how it's making the answer more confusing. hence, removed reference.